# Python POST to AWX API doesn't return Token

Tags: python, rest, ansible-awx

I'm trying to use Python3 with `requests.post()` but it doesn't return the expected payload, while using CURL (Bash) or Invoke-RestMethod (PwSh) I do get the Token for given account, but with the Python code below is like he's doing a GET instead the POST

```
request_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
request_data = {"description": "AWX CLI Token"}
targeturl =(f"{awx_url}/api/v2/users/{user_id}/personal_tokens")
request = requests.post(targeturl, headers=request_headers, verify=False, data=request_data, auth=(awx_user,awx_pass ))
```

I've tried also different variations of the `request.post()` like using `json=json.dumps(request_data)`.

There is no error, return 200.

Comment: So *what* does the endpoint return? can you post what is stored in `request.text` ?

Comment: It does return the JSON of the content of /api/v2/users/.../personal_tokens, where all Tokens are masked - same as if I do a GET to that endpoint. Behave basically as if he's not doing a POST

Comment: try changing `data=` parameter in `requests.post` to `json=`

Comment: Tried, same result. There is 200 but I don't get what I should get in the post, is simply get the whole JSON with all values, not the new value that should be created by the POST. 

I also tried sending just the POST with no Data or additional values as they're not mandatory for such call